# small app with bad practices on node.js and vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, to-do-list

Can someone help me to understand and give me code review of my small todos APP, why my code in backend is bad? Also give me a answers for some of my questions, please:

1. Where my code is bad?
2. Where do I use bad combinations with callback and `async`/`await`?

And show me how it should look in a best code practices, please.

I Attached link for my app on github:
https://github.com/datagramm/ThinkMobiles

I was learning a lot of techniques and approaches but I don't know what I do wrong :(

dashboard controller

```
const User = require("../../models/User");
const Helpers = require('../dashboard/helpers')

const getAllUsers = async (req,res) => {

    await User
        .find()
        .skip(5 * (req.query.page - 1))
        .sort({[req.query.sortValue] : req.query.sortDirection})
        .limit(5)
        .exec(async (err, users) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json(err)
            const completeUsers = await Helpers.getCurrentEventForAllUsers(users)
            User.count().exec( (err,count) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).json(err)
                res.status(200).json({
                    users:completeUsers,
                    accessDenied: req.body.accessDenied,
                    currentUser: req.body.currentUserName,
                    page: +req.query.page,
                    pages: Math.ceil(count / 5)
                });
            })
        })


}



const getCurrentUser = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({id: req.params.id})
        .exec((err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(404).json(err)
            res.status(200).json(user)
        })
}

const getCurrentUserEvents = (req,res) => {

    const skip = 5 * (req.query.page - 1);
    const limit = 5;
    const sort = `events.${req.query.sortValue}`
    const id = req.query.currentUser.id

     User.aggregate([
        { $match: {id: parseInt(id)}},
         { $project: {
                 id: 1,
                 firstName: 1,
                 lastName: 1,
                 phoneNumber: 1,
                 mail: 1,
                 eventCount: 1,
                 firstEventDate: 1,
                 events: {$slice: ['$events', skip, limit]}
             }},
         { $unwind: '$events' },
         { $sort: {
                 [sort]: parseInt(req.query.sortDirection)
             }}
    ],function (err, user){
         if (err) return res.status(500).json(err)
        console.log(user)
        User.findOne({id: id})
            .exec((err, userCount) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).json(err)
                res.status(200).json({
                    user: user,
                    page: +req.query.page,
                    pages: Math.ceil(userCount.events.length / 5)
                })
            })
    } )

}

const pushUser = (req,res) => {
    User.find().exec(async (err, users) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err)
        let id;
        id = users.length
        if (!users) id = 1
        const newUser = await  new User({id: id, firstName: req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName, phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber, mail: req.body.mail, eventCount: 0, firstEventDate: 0}).save()
        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    })

}



const pushEventDate = async (req, res) => {
    let {
        startEventYear,
        startEventMonth,
        startEventDay,
        endEventYear,
        endEventMonth,
        endEventDay
    } =  req.body.event;

    let {id, firstName, lastName, phone, mail} =  req.body.currentUser;

    if (!isNaN(+startEventMonth) && !isNaN(+startEventYear) && !isNaN(+startEventDay)
        && !isNaN(+endEventMonth) && !isNaN(+endEventYear) && !isNaN(+endEventDay)
    ) {
        if (startEventMonth.length === 1) startEventMonth = '0' + startEventMonth;
        if (startEventYear.length === 1) startEventYear = '0' + startEventYear;
        if (startEventDay.length === 1) startEventDay = '0' + startEventDay;
        if (endEventMonth.length === 1) endEventMonth = '0' + endEventMonth;
        if (endEventYear.length === 1) endEventYear = '0' + endEventYear;
        if (endEventDay.length === 1) endEventDay = '0' + endEventDay;

        if (startEventMonth.length === 2 && startEventYear.length === 4 && startEventDay.length === 2 &&
            endEventMonth.length === 2 && endEventYear.length === 4 && endEventDay.length === 2
        ) {
            const currentStarEventDate = startEventYear.toString() + '/' + startEventMonth.toString() + '/' + startEventDay.toString();
            const currentEndEventDate = endEventYear.toString() + '/' + endEventMonth.toString() + '/' + endEventDay.toString();



            const user = await User.findOne({
                id: id,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                phoneNumber: phone,
                mail: mail
            })
            if (user) {

                const checkIs =  user.events.some(event => {
                    if (Helpers.intercept(new Date(`${event.startEventDate}`), new Date(`${event.endEventDate}`),
                        new Date(`${currentStarEventDate}`),
                        new Date(`${currentEndEventDate}`))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })

                if (checkIs) res.send({error: true});
                else {
                    let id;
                    id = user.events.length
                    if (!user.events) id = 1

                    const event = {
                        id: id,
                        tittle: req.body.event.tittle,
                        description: req.body.event.description,
                        startEventDate: currentStarEventDate,
                        endEventDate: currentEndEventDate,

                    }

                    await User.findOneAndUpdate({
                        firstName: req.body.currentUser.firstName,
                        lastName: req.body.currentUser.lastName,
                        phoneNumber: req.body.currentUser.phone,
                        mail: req.body.currentUser.mail,
                    }, {$inc: {eventCount: 1}, $push: {events: event}}, {new: true}).then( (user) => {
                        if (user) {

                            const now = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
                            let closest = {
                                date: Infinity,
                                closest: null,
                            }

                            user.events.forEach( (event) => {

                                const date = new Date(event.startEventDate);
                                if (date >= now  && (date < new Date(closest.date) || date < closest.date)) {
                                    closest = {
                                        date: date,
                                        closest: event.startEventDate
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            User.findOneAndUpdate({
                                firstName: req.body.currentUser.firstName,
                                lastName: req.body.currentUser.lastName,
                                phoneNumber: req.body.currentUser.phone,
                                mail: req.body.currentUser.mail,
                            },{firstEventDate:closest.closest}, {new: true}).then(async(user) =>{
                                if (user) res.send(event);
                            })

                        }
                    })

                }

            }

        }

    }
}

module.exports = {getAllUsers, getCurrentUserEvents, pushUser, pushEventDate, getCurrentUser}
```

dashboard helpers functions

```
const getCurrentEventDate = (user) => {
    const currentDate = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
    let closest = {
        date: Infinity,
        closest: null,
    }
    user.events.forEach((event) => {

        const date = new Date(event.startEventDate);
        if (date >= currentDate && (date < new Date(closest.date) || date < closest.date)) {
            closest = {
                date: date,
                closest: event.startEventDate
            }
        }
    });
    user.firstEventDate = closest.closest;
    return user
}

const getCurrentEventForAllUsers = async (users) => {
    let completeUsers = []
    await users.forEach(user => {
        completeUsers.push(getCurrentEventDate(user))
    })
    return completeUsers;

}

const intercept = (start1, end1, start2, end2) => {
    return (Math.max(0, Math.min(end2, end1) - Math.max(start1, start2) + 1)) > 0
}

module.exports = {getCurrentEventForAllUsers, intercept}
```

user authorization controller

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const Client = require("../models/Client");
const Session = require("../models/Session");
const registerUser = (req, res) => {
    const {username, password, mail} = req.body;
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
        new Client({
            login: username,
            mail: mail,
            password: hash,
        }).save().then( () => {
            res.status(200).json({success: true, err: false});
        }).catch( err => {
            if (err) res.status(500).json({success: false, err: err});
        });


    });
};

const login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const user = await Client.findOne({login: username});
    if (!user) {
        res.status(401).json({err: true,  message: 'User not found'})
        return
    }
    const dbPassword = user.password;
    bcrypt.compare(password, dbPassword).then( async (match) => {
        if (!match) res.status(401).json({err: true, message: 'Wrong password'});
        else {
            req.body.userName = await user.login
            next()
        }

    });

}

const logout = (req,res) => {
    const refreshTokenId = req.cookies["refreshTokenId"];
    Session.findOneAndDelete({"refreshToken.id": refreshTokenId});

    res.clearCookie('refreshTokenId');
    res.clearCookie('accessTokenId');

    res.status(200).json({logout: true})


}

module.exports = {registerUser, login, logout}
```

user session controller

```
const Session = require('../models/Session')
const {sign} = require('jsonwebtoken')
const uuid = require("uuid");
const createSession =  (req, res) => {


    const accessTokenId = sign({login: req.body.userName}, process.env.SECRET_JWT, {expiresIn: '10s'})
    const refreshTokenId =  uuid.v4();
    new Session({
        userName: req.body.userName,
        refreshToken: {
            id: refreshTokenId,
            timeExp: '60d',
        }
    }).save();

    res.cookie('accessTokenId', accessTokenId,{  httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true },);
    res.cookie('refreshTokenId', refreshTokenId,{ maxAge: 5184000000, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none',secure: true},);
    res.status(200).json({err: false})
}

module.exports = {createSession}
```

session validation middleware

```
const {sign, verify} = require('jsonwebtoken')
const uuid = require('uuid')
const Session = require('../models/Session');

const validateSession = async (req,res,next) =>{
    const accessTokenId =  req.cookies["accessTokenId"];
    const refreshTokenId = req.cookies["refreshTokenId"]

    try {
        const access = verify(accessTokenId, process.env.SECRET_JWT)
        if(access) {
            const session = await Session.findOne({"refreshToken.id": refreshTokenId})
            req.body.accessDenied = true;
            const userName = session.userName
            req.body.currentUserName = userName
            next()
        }
    }
    catch (err){
        if (err){
            const session = await Session.findOne({"refreshToken.id": refreshTokenId})

            if (!session) res.status(401).json({users:false, accessDenied: false})
            else {
                const userName = session.userName
                req.body.currentUserName = userName
                const newRefreshTokenId =  uuid.v4();
                await Session.findOneAndUpdate({"refreshToken.id": refreshTokenId},
                    {
                        refreshToken: {id: newRefreshTokenId, timeExp: '60d'},
                    }, {new: true}).then(() =>{
                    const newAccessTokenId = sign({login: session.userName },process.env.SECRET_JWT, {expiresIn: '900s'} )
                    res.cookie('accessTokenId', newAccessTokenId, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true},);
                    res.cookie('refreshTokenId', newRefreshTokenId, {maxAge: 5184000000, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true},);
                    req.body.accessDenied = true;
                    next()
                })


            }
        }
    }
}
module.exports = {validateSession};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews. Please see [_How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Also, if you want more code than that `login` function reviewed then please expand the code here. [Please embed the code to be reviewed directly in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

Comment: Good evening, i need full project code review of my backend part, not only one function  showed here :)